# Change font family and font of delete button in UITableview in Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am using below code to show custom text in place of Delete in swipe to delete in UITableview in Xamarin IOS.

```
public override string TitleForDeleteConfirmation(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {   // Optional - default text is 'Delete'
            return "Move Out";
        }
```

I want to customize the font family and font of this text alone and I do not want it to affect the fonts and font family used else where.

Any pointers on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should figure out the hierarchical relationship of this delete button. It has some difference on different versions.

**On iOS 11:** it's a subview of `UITableView`, so we can get it using the code below. But in my test, there're also some differences between XCode 8 and 9.

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
{
    //foreach (UIView subView in MyTableView.Subviews)
    //{
    //    if (subView.Class.Name.ToString() == "UITableViewWrapperView")
    //    {
    //        foreach (UIView subsubView in subView.Subviews)
    //        {
    //            if (subsubView.Class.Name.ToString() == "UISwipeActionPullView")
    //            {
    //                UIButton deleteBtn = subView.Subviews[0] as UIButton;

    //                //configure the button
    //            }
    //        }
    //    }
    //}
    //For XCode 9.0+
    foreach (UIView subView in MyTableView.Subviews)
    {                  
        if (subView.Class.Name.ToString() == "UISwipeActionPullView")
        {
            UIButton deleteBtn = subView.Subviews[0] as UIButton;

            //configure the button
        }                      
    }
}
```

**On iOS 8-10:** it's a subview of `UITableViewCell`, try to enumerate it like:

```
else
{
    UITableViewCell tableViewCell = MyTableView.CellAt(editingIndexPath);
    foreach (UIView subView in tableViewCell.Subviews)
    {
        if (subView.Class.Name.ToString() == "UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView")
        {
            UIButton deleteBtn = subView.Subviews[0] as UIButton;

            //configure the button
        }
    }
}
```

We need to get each cell when user swipe to show the delete button. We can get it in the event:

```
public class MyTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
{
    ViewController superViewController;

    public MyTableViewSource(ViewController viewController)
    {
        superViewController = viewController;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override string TitleForDeleteConfirmation(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return "Move Out";
    }

    public override void WillBeginEditing(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        superViewController.editingIndexPath = indexPath;
        //use this method to fire "ViewDidLayoutSubviews()"
        superViewController.View.SetNeedsLayout();
    }

    public override void DidEndEditing(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        superViewController.editingIndexPath = null;
    }

    public override void CommitEditingStyle(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

    }    
}
```

After setting this, `ViewDidLayoutSubviews()` will fire before delete button shown. So we need to call the configuration method we create above in `ViewDidLayoutSubviews()`:

```
public NSIndexPath editingIndexPath;
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

    if (editingIndexPath != null)
    {
        //This method is the code what I post above, implement on different iOS versions.
        configSwipeActions();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## steps:

1 click on cell in your storybord
2 set class name on your  property bar
3 created class inside find your control(simply type your control name is appear?  );
4 set your_controll.Font= (UIFont.FromName("Helvetica",10);)